# Find white-space at the front in SQL data

Tags: sql

Thank you for your help.

How do I get data that contains a space at the front or the back?

For example: (see .png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tinC.png)

I tried:

```
select* from customer_table where customer like '% %'
```

but:

it gave me all of them because name contains a space in between.

I need to get the ones that have a white-space at the front.

thank you!

Comment: If you want it to start with a space, remove the first wildcard in the like: `select* from customer_table where customer like ' %'`

Comment: First you say "_at the front or the back_", then you say "_the ones that have a white-space at the front_". What do you want?

Comment: The title says _white-space_, but then you talk about _space_. Whar do you want?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where customer like ' %' or customer like '% '
```

`like` patterns match the entire string.  So the first gets spaces at the begging and the second spaces at the end.  If you wanted *both*, you can do that in a single patter:

```
where customer like ' % '
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRIM` function on the column to fit you select condition, for instance

```
WHERE LTRIM([CUSTOMER]) = 'Joe'
```

This example is for Microsoft SQL Server but I believe all DBMS have a similar function you can use trim as the keyword to search.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.